# Input validation loop in java

Tags: java

How would I write an input validation loop and at least one other loop, either counter-controlled or sentinel-controlled. Could you help me how to write any type of code?

Comment: Please show us what you already have tried.

Comment: /*
** I have created a program
** Which takes user input and removes the characters other
** than alphabets and numbers.
** It also prints the Final qualified User Name
**
** Used 2 loops (while and for), one to validate and other to print
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Array of length 16 to store username
char inp[16];
// variable to store validated username length
int userNameLength;

Comment: void getUserInput();
void printQualifiedUserName();

int main()
{
    // calling function to get user input
    getUserInput();

    if(userNameLength<1) printf("Your Username do not contain even a single Qualified character in it. Shame on you! \:\)\n");
    else printQualifiedUserName();

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void getUserInput(){
    char c;
    printf("Enter Username (only alphaNumeric): ");

    int i = 0;

Comment: // Looping till user pressed ENTER (\n)
    while((c=getchar())!='\n'){

        // validating every character entered
        if(isalpha(c) || isdigit(c)){
            // Breaking the loop after username length is 16
            if(i>15) break;
            // storing qualified characters
            inp[i] = c;
            i++;
        }
    }

    userNameLength = i;
}

void printQualifiedUserName(){
    printf("User Name after validating: \n");

    int i;
    // Another loop to print the user name
    for(i=0;i<userNameLength;i++){
        putchar(inp[i]);
    }
}

Comment: Please edit your question to add that information. It's not readable in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

```
final int SIZE = 10;
    int [] array = new int[SIZE];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        try 
        {
            do
            {
                System.out.print("Enter Number " + (i+1) + ": ");
                array[i] = input.nextInt();

                if(array[i] < 0)
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input - Must be Greater than 0");

            }while(array[i] < 0);

        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input - Not an Int - Re-Enter");

            input.nextLine();
            i--;
        }
    }
```